# jQuery click is not working on iPhone (only)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Update: Code was fine. There was problem in css. I used `position : fixed;` and did not set `left` property. As I added `left: 0;` it worked fine.

Thank to all of you

---

```
$('#menu-drop').click(function(){
    $('#site-navigation').toggleClass("dropdown-show");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shktjeao/

I'm working on Wordpress theme but jQuery function is not working on iPhone or Safari(mac). It works on iPad, Chrome (mac).

When I run the code on jsfiddle, it works fine on all devices.

My wordpress is [here](http://pressimpress.kr).

How can I fix this?

Comment: that icon hit area for finger might not be enough.. try increasing the width and height

Answer (score -1):

try use this code

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu-drop', function () {
   $('#site-navigation').toggleClass("dropdown-show");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For iOS devices you'll need to listen for touchstart, too:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '#menu-drop', function() { 
  $('#site-navigation').toggleClass("dropdown-show");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a **pointer cursor** to the button and use `.on` to bind click event

**Example:** https://output.jsbin.com/fisuhuzima

```
$('#menu-drop').css('cursor','pointer');
$(document).on('click', '#menu-drop',  function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#site-navigation').toggleClass("dropdown-show");
});
```